# Joomla! VirtueMart - Registration form doesn't display USERNAME and PASSWORD fields

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart, joomla-module

I'm using Joomla! 1.5.14 and VirtueMart 1.1.3

I'm using mod_virtuemart's login control in my website. When i run my site and clicked on 'register', it shows a registration form. But i realised that there isn't fields for USERNAME and PASSWORD.

I logged in as administrator, and looked under 'Manage User Fields'.
Username, password, and password2 have TICKS under "required", "published", "Show in registration form" and "Show in account maintenance".

But why is it that when i run my site, the fields are not shown?

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla portion. Have you gone to Global Configuration -> System -> User Settings and set 'Allow User Registration' to 'Yes'?

This is the only thing I can think of without actually trying to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

In Virtuemart under:
Configuration
Global Tab
User Registration Settings
User Registration Type

Check to make sure it is not set to "No Account Creation"

Hope this helps!